# Register jumping to high numbers when reading values from memory Assembly i386

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, i386

I've been trying to learn assembly. So for practice I'm trying to code snake, and I've run into an  issue.

Whenever I try to load the value of `direction_offset` into a register it just becomes absurdly large. I'm expecting it to become 3 but instead if becomes 251785475. Could anyone explain to me why this happens?

Snippet from .data section:

```
direction_offset db 3
direction db -15,1,15,-1
```

```
        ; grab offset to new position from array
        mov esi, [direction_offset]
        mov edi, [direction + esi]
```

gdp output:

```
198     mov esi, [direction_offset]
(gdb) info register esi
esi            0xe1                225
(gdb) step
199     mov edi, [direction + esi]
(gdb) info register esi
esi            0xf01f103           251785475
(gdb)
```

In case it matters, I compiled the code using nasm like this:

```
#compile
nasm -g -f elf -F dwarf $asmname
ld -m elf_i386 -o $name $outputname
```

Comment: You loaded 4 bytes from your `db` byte array into a dword register, so yeah; look at the register value in hex and you'll see the value you wanted in the low byte.  Use a `movzx` load.  (But kudos for at least using a debugger to narrow down the problem to just this.  We get a lot of variations of this question where people loaded a dword that overlaps multiple bytes, so if someone wants to write up a canonical answer, this is probably the nicest question, nice [mcve] and not a lot of noise.)

Comment: @PeterCordes
Def going to try that tomorrow when I pick it back up. thanks!